# isEqualToArray crashes with custom class

Tags: ios, nsarray, compare

I have an application that has an array of 5 objects. These objects are all of a custom class. The next iteration of the loop and after some modifications to a temporary array I run a check to see if the values are the same or different by using `isEqualToArray`. However, the minute I do that I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Is there something that I need to implement in the class to prevent this from happening.

Without giving away too much information the custom class only stores 5 `NSString*` variables.

Comment: Could you provide sample code? P.S. If you start a loop for the array and you modify that array you could have crashes. In other words you cannot modify the array while you are looping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your NSString variables have been released and your accessing bad memory.

Do you remove them from the array? Or do you possibly create them with autorelease semantics, put them into the array and then release them too?

Maybe post a little more code and we can tell you exactly what is wrong, but more than likely they have been released.

You can turn on NSZombieEnabled to see exactly what is being 'badly accessed'

Comment: You're right. I did release the object after I added it to the array. I thought it followed the same layout as adding a view to a subview. Once you add it you would immediately release it. I guess the the same is not true for NSMutableArrays

Comment: It's nothing to do with the type of container, whether its a UIView or a NSMutableArray. It's to do with how the object was created and the ownership. You only call release on an object you own. You only own an object if you obtained it by using alloc,copy,new,retain. So when you created your UIView, you probably used alloc:initWithFrame: so you owned it, and had to call release. When you created the NSString you probably used a convenience autorelease method such as stringWithFormat ..which you don't own, so don't call release on it. Have a look at the memory rules again (or use ARC).